# Android View Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a bar at the top of my android app that has three buttons and a logo, one button on the far left, logo centered, and two buttons on the right side.  My issue is that the two buttons on the right side are overlapping, how do I get them both to be on the right side but not stacked?

Here is my XML structure for the view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="42px" 
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:background="@drawable/header_background">

    <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_white" 
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/camera_button"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/two_up_button"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any advice would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both `button_switch` and `button_camera` are aligned right inside the parent as the obvious attribute states: `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Use the attributes `layout_toLeftOf` or `layout_toRightOf` to specify in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first button (`button_camera`) needs to be aligned to the right of `button_switch` using `layout_toRightOf="@id/button_switch`.

Answer (score -1):

Just needed another RelativeLayout-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="42px" 
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:background="@drawable/header_background">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bloom_logo_white" 
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"

            />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/camera_button"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_camera">

            <Button android:id="@+id/button_switch"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text=""
       android:background="@drawable/two_up_button"
       android:layout_gravity="right"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nested container layouts should be avoided wherever possible. The value in RelativeLayout is the special attributes it provides for its children (see the other answers) to allow for complex layouts with minimal nesting.  While this answer may achieve the result you want, it goes against best practices because layouts nested too deeply can cause performance issues and complicate your code.  In fact, the outer LinearLayout in the example code should probably be removed, as its only child is a RelativeLayout which takes up all of the parent's space.

Comment: No problem, you're on the right track!  Check out this link: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html  It's Google's Training page for beginning developers.  You can find some basic layout tips, as well as other information on building apps there.  It's very informative and can really help you think about things in an Android-y way.